# how to split huge html to little files

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to take a massive html file and split it to sections. The file is generated by Jenkins and looks like this:

```
[XXX] text1
[XXX] text2
[YYY] text4
[XXX] text3
[YYY] text5
[ZZZ] text6
...
```

I tried to do the following:

```
my_dict = {}
text, header = re.split('\n\[[A-Za-z]+\]'), re.match('\n\[[A-Za-z]+\]')
for idx, (header, text) in enumerate(zip(header, text)):
    try:
        my_dict[header] += text
    except KeyError:
        my_dict[header] = text
    print idx
```

but that takes way too long (idx is ~ 200K). Can I do that faster somehow?

Comment: What is expected format?

Comment: How many different headers are there? If there are a lot, you'll be hitting that `except` a lot, and catching exceptions is slow.

Comment: I hope to achieve a dict with {'XXX' : text1 text2 text3, 'YYY' text4 text5} and then write it to different files

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 there about 10 headers tops and about 40K items on each header, so I used try instead of if

Comment: Can you iterate over the file line by line and split the header from the text for each line with a simple `str.partition` or `str.split`, avoiding the `re.split`? Also, you're printing each `idx`, and printing is actually pretty slow.

Answer (score 1):

ok, solved it... I split the loop to 10K steps, and that just made it run crazy fast in comperaion. Guess I was just taking up too much RAM